# Nested fields "Cannot read property 'zip' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Having this error. **Any idea how to solve it?**

Object from MongoDB:

```
...
"name" : true,
"address" : {
        "zip" : "BH9AXX",
        ...
```

Request to the db:

```
exports.getList = function (req, res, next) {
    User.find({
        user: req.user.id
    }, function (err, users) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        return res.render('list', {
            users: users
        });

    });
};
```

list.jade:

```
each user in users
    tr
      td #{user.name}
      td #{user.address.zip}
```

Everything works correctly, when #{user.address.zip} is not used.

Answer (score 1):

`user.address` is undefined (at least in some cases) and so the attempt to access `user.address.zip` in the jade file results in the error.

Possible solutions include:

- Perhaps address is not a required field in your db schema or it is allowed to be undefined. If so, perhaps you can make it required.
- You can add code before calling `res.render()` that checks to see if `user.address` is undefined. If so, set it to a default value (such as an object with `zip` set as an empty string).

Comment: Indeed. user.address is undefined